# How to use an argument as return value in gmock

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have the following call:

```
EXPECT_CALL(myMock, myFunction(someSpecifiedParameter, _, _))
      .WillOnce(DoAll(SaveArg<2>(&bufferSize), Return(make_pair(Success, bufferSize))));
```

I'm trying to return whatever value that is passed as the second `_` as my second element in the pair. Is it the best (or at least right) way to do it?

This bufferSize variable was declared in the test class.

EDIT:

Putting in other words:

Suppose I have the following:

```cpp
class object{
    pair<int, int> f(int x);
}

object obj;
constexpr int fixedValue = 5;
EXPECT_CALL(obj, f(_)).WillOnce(
                       Return(make_pair(fixedValue, <PARAMETER PASSED TO F>));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is right, you deanonymize the value in the third parameter. In my opinion using a lambda or a custom actions is the more preferable way. A stored lambda or an action can be reused in other expectations.

```
EXPECT_CALL(myMock, myFunction(someSpecifiedParameter, _, _))
  .WillOnce(WithArgs<0, 2>([](Type1 Success, Type2 bufferSize) {
    return make_pair(Success, bufferSize);
  }));
```

or

```
ACTION_P2(ReturnPair, Success, bufferSize) {
  return make_pair(Success, bufferSize);
}

EXPECT_CALL(myMock, myFunction(someSpecifiedParameter, _, _))
  .WillOnce(WithArgs<0, 2>(ReturnPair));
```

More specialized thus less preferable

```
EXPECT_CALL(myMock, myFunction(someSpecifiedParameter, _, _))
  .WillOnce(WithArg<2>([](Type2 bufferSize) {
    return make_pair(someSpecifiedParameter, bufferSize);
  }));
```

or

```
ACTION_P(ReturnPair, bufferSize) {
  return make_pair(someSpecifiedParameter, bufferSize);
}

EXPECT_CALL(myMock, myFunction(someSpecifiedParameter, _, _))
  .WillOnce(WithArg<2>(ReturnPair));
```

Comment: But by calling that wouldn't I pass `someSpecifiedParameter` to be replaced in `Success` ? Success in my case is a constant. I would like to have `pair<SUCCESS_CONSTANT, ARG2>`

Comment: I do not get what you mean. When `WillOnce` raises, the arg 0 has the value `someSpecifiedParameter`.

Comment: The way I'm trying to do doesn't work. Somehow the statements are not begin evaluated in order (`SaveArg` and `Return`).

Comment: I think your solution would work If I had SUCCESS as a parameter... but when I try to use ACTION_P it seems to want to deduce a return of int... and If I try to cheat by putting 2 parameters but ignoring the first one to use the constant instead the compiler also complains.

Comment: I'm updating some legacy code. It used to set out parameters inside and I changed to return tuples instead. I just realized that instead of trying to get the value being passed I could add more legibility by passing a name instead of `_` and using that same name in the tuple creation.

Comment: I understand your solution, it just didn't work my case because the current test we have here is not well written. The lesson that I got from here is: If one needs to get the value of a `_`, then he probably should know the value that was passed to it and should name it.

Comment: I didn't notice that you had changed the first code sample (thought you just added stuff below, sorry about that). The solution with lambda is what I needed!